# Change value from $watchgroup

Tags: angularjs

I have a problem with `$watchgroup`.

This is my code :

```
$scope.$watchGroup(['field1', 'field2', 'field3', 'field4', 'field5', 'field6', 'field7', 'field8'], function(newValues, oldValues, scope) {  
}
```

Inside watchGroup, I have to check how much fields are different from `undefined`. When I have three fields compiled, If user try to compile the fourth field, that field have to return `undefined`.

How can I do that?

Comment: It's not really clear what you are trying to accomplish here.  What do you mean, "if user try to compile the fourth field"?  That doesn't make sense.

Comment: It is like a max choice. User can be compile only 3 of 8 fields. If he try to compile 4 fields, that field have to return undefined

Comment: so this is for form validation?  that's not really what `$watchGroup` is meant for.

Comment: I have 20 md-select(angularMaterial). User can select value but in only 3 md-select.  If user had compiled 3 fields and he try to compile another field, this have to return undefined

Comment: right, you've said that multiple times, but this is still not what `$watchGroup` is for.  you can't modify the group you are watching, it will cause an infinite loop.

Comment: oh, ok.. And, how can I do?